# List items that each contain a different Carousel Item

Tags: sxa

Based on the folder structure below, I am trying to display all the locations on a page, each of them having their own carousel item (each carousel item has different images inside.) I can display a carousel for each item using rendering variants (insert a placeholder and assign a carousel to it) but I can't find a way to point each carousel component to its correspondent carousel item.

[image]

Does anyone know of an out of the box way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this won't be possible with Page List + variant with the placeholder. In general, it might be hard to achieve this out of the box.
I would try to output just images and then use Java Script to turn HTML into a carousel.

The problem with list components and placeholders in variants is that for example, Page List is not switching context item. For the placeholder generated by Page List current page list item should be taken as a context item. But I'm afraid that it's not like that and page on which Page List is placed is treated as a context item.

I knew that we were discussing this problem some time ago but I'm not sure if this has already been solved. I would need to check this...